# Preemptive close reason watch

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Who can watch the close reasons for a question which has *some*, but not yet *sufficient* close votes? And how to watch? (Moderator tools, probably. For the obvious reason to preemptively improve the question. I myself have encountered enough "stray" close votes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[On your own questions](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) you need 250 reputation points to see close votes.

[On other people's questions](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) you need 500 reputation.

Comment: Ah, now I see. Close button is quasi-overloaded, on an own question it does a different thing. Guess why I never tried it :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are no moderator tools for this, but you can keep an eye on the Close Votes review queue; questions with active close votes will appear there ~15 minutes after the first vote.